# APEX 19.1 Form that allows insert of multiple records on the same table at the same time

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I've created a form which I would like it to be able to insert 3 records at once in one table.

[print screen of form page with modal form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcN6l.jpg)

**GUIA_TRANSPORTE** is a value passed from the page to the modal.

At the moment,

If I only fill the first row of input items, it inserts on the table the correct **GUIA_TRANSPORTE** value but **Product** and **quantidade** inserts as null values.

If I only fill the last row of input items, it inserts that row with the correct values into the table.

If I fill everything, it inserts only the last row of input items into my table.

So, how can I make it insert all 3 rows with the correct values? and also being able to fill only the first row of items and it to insert the right values (aka not null) into my table

Comment: You're almost certainly going to have to describe the implementation/ show your code to get any help.  It is very unlikely that someone is going to be able to tell from a screenshot of your application's layout why your application's code isn't working the way you want it to.

Comment: I think the code i use to pass the value onto the modal dialog and to open it is irrelevant since this applies to every form when i try to make it into a multi-row insertion form.

Comment: I don't think the code to pass the value to the modal is relevant, but how was your modal form constructed? Is it a classic report or regular form? Are there always three rows or can that vary? What happens when you submit the page? Are you executing custom PL/SQL code (if so, that would be relevant)?

Answer (score 0):

I seems that you are using automatic row processing when the page is submitted, but you should probably use PL/SQL code in the page processing:

```
IF (Product1 is not null and quantidade1 is not null) then
    insert into TABLENAME (GUIA_TRANSPORTE, Product, quantidade) values (PXX_GUIA_TRANSPORTE, PXX_Product1, PXX_quantidade1 )
END IF;

IF (PXX_Product2 is not null and PXX_quantidade2 is not null) then
    insert into TABLENAME (GUIA_TRANSPORTE, Product, quantidade) values (PXX_GUIA_TRANSPORTE, PXX_Product2, PXX_quantidade2 )
END IF;

IF (PXX_Product3 is not null and PXX_quantidade3 is not null) then
    insert into TABLENAME (GUIA_TRANSPORTE, Product, quantidade) values (PXX_GUIA_TRANSPORTE, PXX_Product3, PXX_quantidade3)
END IF;
```

Good luck!